# Replacing second column using shell script

Tags: sed, awk, grep, shell

I want to change the second column to upper case and I want to do it in shell script only. (no one liners!)

```
#!/bin/sh
# read file line by line
file="/pdump/country.000000.txt"
while read line
do
mycol=`echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $2}'`
mycol_new=`echo $mycol | tr "[:lower:]" [:upper:]`
echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $1 "," $mycol_new "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8}'
done < $file
```

I am not able to replace the $2 with $mycol_new.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` cannot see `$mycol_new` because it is a shell variable. Here is one way of passing a shell variable into awk using the `-v` flag:

```
echo $line | awk -v var="$mycol_new" -F"," '{print $1 "," var "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8}'
```

Here is an alternative method which lets the shell expand `$mycol_new`:

```
echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $1 ",'"$mycol_new"'," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8}'
```

Comment: I am using the first method suggested by you. The only problem is that if I have text \N in the third or fifth column it is converted to N (sans slash) How do I preserve the text as it is.

Comment: @shantanuo awk strips out the backslash if it's not one of the recognized escape sequences. So if it was \n, awk would have recognized it as newline but \N is simply interpreted as N. More details here http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html Perhaps you should use one of the answers below that doesn't use awk.

Answer (score 2):

why no one liners? Doing homework?

```
$ cat file
one two three four
five six seven eight

$ awk '{$2=toupper($2)}1' file
one TWO three four
five SIX seven eight
```

Comment: Some older versions of AWK may not have `toupper()`, otherwise +1.

Comment: i don't think OP is using old version. even `nawk` has it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this all in the shell, then you don't need awk:

```
IFS=,
while read line; do
  set -- $line
  a="$1"
  b="${2^^}"  # assumes bash, use "tr" otherwise
  shift 2
  set -- "$a" "$b" "$@"
  echo "$*"
done < "$file" > "$file.new"
```

Comment: Correction: "# assumes bash **4**"