# awk changes the text unexpectedly

Tags: shell, loops, awk, while-loop

I am using the following awk statement in my shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
# read file line by line
file="/pdump/country.000000.txt"
while read line
do
mycol=`echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $2}'`
mycol_new=`echo $mycol | tr "[:lower:]" [:upper:]`
echo $line | awk -v var="$mycol_new" -F"," '{print $1 "," var "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8}'
done < $file
```

It is working as expected.

The only problem is that if the original text is \N (slash N) in any other column for e.g. $4 or $7 then it changes to N (without slash). 
How do I preserve the original values while replacing only the second column.

Comment: The loss of the backslash must be happening elsewhere. If you `echo $line` without the `awk` command, do you see backslash N?

Comment: You are correct. even if I use echo "$line" it shows the line without \N How do I correct this problem. What tag should I use for this question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338225/replacing-second-column-using-shell-script # I am using the while loop to read the file lines

Comment: I have posted a fix for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-r` option for `read` in your `while` loop:

```
while read -r line
```

That preserves backslashes in the input. That option should almost always be used. Make it a habit.

Answer (score 0):

awk strips out the backslash if it's not one of the recognized escape sequences. So if it was \n, awk would have recognized it as newline but \N is simply interpreted as N. More details [here](http://math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, you are trying:

1. Read input from a comma-separated-values (CSV) file
2. Change the second field to uppercase
3. Print the result.

If that is the case, use AWK directly. Save the following to toupper_second_field.awk:

```
BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS="," }
{ $2 = toupper($2); print }
```

The first line sets the field separators for both input (FS) and output (OFS) to comma. The second converts field #2 to upper case, then print. To invoke it:

```
awk -f toupper_second_field.awk /pdump/country.000000.txt
```

The logic is much simpler and you don't have to worry about backslashes.